# Puppeteer - How to change orientation of some pages in a document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to create a 30-page long pdf and a few of the pages need to be landscape orientated. How can I specify it only for page x and page y ?

Comment: What did you try? where are you stuck? What does your code and HTML look like?

Comment: I agree with the question above. However I can also say it's pretty complicated to change specific page orientation. Gonna research this. Feels like a limitation of chrome.

Comment: I added some answer which complies with `some pages` but not `page X`.

Comment: [markdown-preview-enhanced/blob/master/docs/puppeteer.md](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/blob/master/docs/puppeteer.md)

Answer (score 8):

## Pseudo Selectors for @page

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) or [CSS spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule), you can set up different orientation to some pages using CSS.

```
@page :pseudo-selector{
 size: landscape;
}
```

The acceptable and working pseudo-selectors (that I tested with puppeteer and google chrome) includes,

```
:blank
:first
:left
:right
```

Result:
[image]

PS: At the moment of answer, other selectors like `:nth-child` and page identifies mentioned on the draft does not work on chrome version 73.

## Alternative way

The only other way to deal with this is to print pages separately and then merge them later on. You can print specific pages with `pageRanges`,

```
page.pdf({pageRanges: '1-5', path: 'first.pdf'})
```

And use packages like `pdf-merge` to merge two pdf file.

```
const PDFMerge = require('pdf-merge');
PDFMerge(['first.pdf', 'second.pdf'], {output: `${__dirname}/3.pdf`})
```

Comment: it took me a while to figure out that you do not necessarily need the pseudo selectors. at least in my case using the CLI of https://github.com/Codeuctivity/PuppeteerSharp.Renderer it was enough to add `@page { size: landscape; }` to my styles

Answer (score 3):

Well, according to caniuse, [you can use the page property with Chrome 85 and up](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_page)

So you can use **@page** followed by a "named page name" in combination with **the page property** to set a different orientation (or any other properties) to any page you want.

example:

```
@page rotated {
   size: landscape;
}

.rotated_class {
   page: rotated;
}
```

[Page example, just right click -> print to see it in action](https://geh.neocities.org/print.html)

**EDIT**

Well, after writing this solution I found a major problem with the `@page` approach. If you try to print the example page I linked to just above, you'll see that the viewport of the rotated pages is limited to the width of the first page if the first page is in portrait (and limited in height if the first page is in landscape).

The solution I ended up using for the page rotation is a bit whack and needs a second library, but it works :

- Set a different size on the pages you want to be rotated (here I change it by 0.1 inch which is about 1 pixel in the end) and assign it to your corresponding pages

```
    @page rotated {
       size: 8.49in 11in;
    }

    .rotated_class {
       page: rotated;
    }
```

- I use `pdf-lib` after the puppeteer generation to open the pdf and rotate every page smaller than a normal page (in my case I check if the width is smaller than 612 pixels)

```
  const pages = pdf.getPages();
  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; ++i) {
    const pageToRotate = pages[i];
    if (pageToRotate.getWidth() < 612) {
      pageToRotate.setRotation(degrees(-90));
    }
  }
  pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(await pdf.save());
```

- the Page size is the only info I found that could be "transferred" from the css to the `pdf-lib` to flag any page to be rotated, hence why I'm using that solution.

Hopefully the "viewport bug" will be fixed in the future and we'll be able to use the @page landscape/portrait property

Comment: @KJ The scale is good, but if you print it with the background colors ON (or with headers+footers), you'll see the colors are cut off  early and that the headers stops on the midlle of the landscape pages

Answer (score 2):

We need to set '**landscape**' property to '**true**' in options.

```
var options = {
    ...
    landscape: true
}

page.pdf(options);
```

Comment: Your answer will set all page to landscape mode -- the question is how to set landscape mode for only a few pages.